# SHA Hash of large files in Windows

Tags: hash

I need a way of verifing the state of some VHD test environments. I am thinking I could generate SHA or MD5 hashes.

How can you generate SHA hashes for large files, some of these VHDs are more than 10GB.

Ideally I would prefer a script solution in Powershell, Python or something wscript will run.

Thanks

Comment: similar q-n I've come up with: http://serverfault.com/a/786364/67675

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't say, if you have tried any of existing tools - and if they didn't suit for some purpose.

I would start with downloading any of a number of command-line SHA generator tools and work from there; check, eg, http://www.labtestproject.com/win/sha1sum.exe.html both for generation and checking.

Comment: Some broken download links on that site, but some work. This tool is fine for me, thanks.